# MATLAB how to set the path before running an executable

Tags: matlab

When the executable runs I'm trying to make it access another folder saved on my flash drive. I have tried adding addpath() before the script but that doesn't work. I am trying to make the executable search for the mcr folder I have installed on my flash drive before running the main project. So far it keeps crashing trying to search for the runtime folder.

Error

```
Could not find version 9.0.1 of MATLAB Runtime.
Attempting to load mclmcrrt9_0_1.dll.
Please install the correct version of the MATLAB Runtime. Contact your vendor if you do not have an installer for the MATLAB Runtime.
```

I understand that when you install the MATLAB Runtime it installs in the C Drive. But I installed it on my flash drive. So that when I used different PC's I didn't have to install the runtime every time. But every time I use a different PC that error always shows. So I'm trying to set the PATH in my executable so that it will always know to find the Runtime folder on my flash drive.

Comment: We need more information. Please provide the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the path before you launch the (matlab created) exe - you cant set it from within Matlab.  You can do this by creating a script, e.g. on windows create `run.bat`  (drive and path to your exe assumed)

```
path = E:\MCR\v90\runtime\win64
yourMatlab.exe
```

Comment: That Worked 100%. Thank you. I just had one more question. Is there a way to automatically detect the drive name (E:\). So if I put the flash drive on another computer that has the drive (J:\). Can I automatically change E:\ to J:\

Comment: If you remove the drive letter and make the path relative to where the script is it should work.